# parse file location dynamical to download

Tags: php, restler

i am using restler framework,and have a  class given below

```
class file {
function upload ($url= ' '){
    echo $url ;
}
}
```

i want to enter a link so that the server downloads the file based on a url,
so if i put this in the browser

```
http://localhost/apiv1/file/upload?url=http://10.220.5.181/New%20folder/02%20Track%202.mp3
```

i get a response

```
Warning: parse_url(/apiv1/file/upload?url=http://10.220.5.181/New%20folder/02%20Track%202.mp3): Unable to parse URL in /usr/share/airtime/public/vendor/Luracast/Restler/Restler.php
```

So what does this mean, and how do i fix it?

PS: note that it does perform the function properly ( ie: it uploads the file)

Comment: Can you provide us contents of /usr/share/airtime/public/vendor/Luracast/Restler/Restler.php ?

Comment: unfortunately, its exceed the length restriction on stackoverflow. it is available here. https://github.com/Luracast/Restler/blob/master/vendor/Luracast/Restler/Restler.php

Comment: I think you are passing the url into restler wrong. Can you post the code where you are getting the url from `?url=`

Comment: i am getting it manually at the moment (copy and paste)

Comment: Because its clearly complaining about that `URL` and its right, thats not really a url since it has `/apiv1/file/upload?url=` preceeding it. Unless thats how its supposed to work?

Comment: That is how it is supposed to work :), what it does is take what ever is after the `=` sign and assigns it to the variable `url`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL is not vaild. You have to `urlencode()` the query values. Please try the following:

```
http://localhost/apiv1/file/upload?url=http%3A%2F%2F10.220.5.181%2FNew%2520folder%2F02%2520Track%25202.mp3
```